# How to handle AskTime out Exception in Playframework?

Tags: akka, playframework-2.1

The play application which we are using, has to be kept always alive. This application is basically a RabbitMQ listener which has an infinite while loop, which keeps listening to capture the messages from Message Queue.

The following code is placed in controller, and this play application has to be kept alive at all times

public class Application extends Controller {

```
public static Result wanHLPT() {
    ckmsg()
    return ok();
}

public static Result ckmsg() {

    try{
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

    channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);

    while (true) {
    QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
    String message = new String(delivery.getBody());
    // business logic
    process()

}
}
}
```

}

But the play application throws akka exception [AskTimeOut Exception: Timed Out],
Please provide any pointers on how to handle this.

Here is the exception:

```
! @6f977jo6m - Internal server error, for (GET) [/myapp] ->

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[AskTimeoutException: Timed out]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:289) ~   [play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:383) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anon$2$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:132) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anon$2$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:128) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Promise.scala:104) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:781) ~[na:1.7.0]
akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Timed out
    at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scala:310) ~[akka-actor_2.10.jar:na]
    at akka.actor.DefaultScheduler$$anon$8.run(Scheduler.scala:193) ~[akka-actor_2.10.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:137) ~[akka-actor_2.10.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1417) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:262) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:975) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1478) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
```

Comment: This timne out occurs after 1hour, since the application is kickstarted. This happens because the play framework, keeps waiting for the http request. Please provide inputs on how to handle this

Comment: You can refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686706/play-framework-2-0-x-asktimeoutexception

Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167702/execution-exceptionasktimeoutexception-timed-out-playframework/19354440#19354440